# Automatically connect WAN Miniport (SSTP) adapter at login

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, network-adapter

I have a WAN Miniport (SSTP) Adapter which I want to automatically connect when I log on.

It authenticates using a certificate in the local users certificate store, no password required. When I click "connect" in the context menu of the adapter, a window pops up where I click "connect" again and it works. `rasdial` doesn't work with this connection.

System is Windows 7 pro, but I'm also interested if it's different for Win8.1.

How to automatically connect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer is already there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17704208/794638). It even says

> **This function is not supported on this system.** 
>   Don't get fooled by this message because its just that you didn't give the correct syntax.

which is what got me fooled.

However, to make it run more seamlessly, some [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window/1802836#1802836) [tweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background) are necessary.

I still have one issue with this: When the connection fails there comes a window up with a "retry"-button and an option to start logging. But I don't want the user to notice anything. It should just run in the background. It's not even that important when it fails, it's more important to happen silently. Any ideas? Comments?